# What does this long sentence mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I have a problem with understanding the bolded sentence below, extracted from a marketing book:

> Currently, margins are tight and turnover is dependent on inclusive tours and business travel respectively, with other services bringing far smaller contribution. The concept of the experience curve, i.e. an increased market share relative to competitors which leads to the creation of economies of scale, is appropriate in this context. **Not only is it a matter of increasing the volume of sales of tourism offerings across branches that improves commercial return, but also the wider experience applied across all activities of the business, which leads to greater profitability.**

Would you please paraphrase it? I know the meaning of every single word but the meaning of the whole sentence is vague.

I think tourism offerings =  tourism products. But, what does "the wider experience applied across all activities of the business" mean? Is "experience" applicable?

Comment: It is a poorly written, run-on sentence. No surprise you're having trouble with it.

Comment: @Robusto Are you a native? Would you please paraphrase it?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence in question breaks down into:

The issue is not just one of increasing sales volumes

of tourism products

among the company's branches

to obtain a better commercial return

but it is also sharing the experience

of all the company's business activities (among the branches)

that leads to greater profitability.

Comment: Thank you! Does "it" in "Not only is it a matter of ..." refer to "the experience curve" in the previous sentence or is it a *dummy it*?

Comment: @Juya Yes, the *it* seems to me to be acting as a dummy *it* in referring to the issue in question - how best to exploit the market.

Comment: Would you please state it in an even simpler structure and words?